# MySQL 5.5.30 INSERT only if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, unique

I am trying to insert a row but only if it doesn't exist yet.

I've had a look through the forums and this syntax appears to be what I want:

```
INSERT INTO tblSites (site,homepage) VALUES ('A','www.a.com') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblSites where homepage='www.a.com')
```

And I get a syntax error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblSites where homepage='www.a.com')' 
at line 1
```

I've read around and everyone seems to be using this syntax, is it not available in the version I'm using or something? I've listed some other options below, but I'd like to understand why this isn't working for my own learning (and sanity).

Other methods I've looked at are:

1) REPLACE. In some others areas where I'm intending on using this query, I have millions of rows and duplicates are likely. I'd only want to use REPLACE if it was comparable in terms of efficiency to the above syntax. Any thoughts?
2) INSERT IGNORE. Might be worth using this, tblSites  currently has (siteId,name,homepage). I could make homepage the id as it will be unique and then I believe this would work (?), but I'm also linking this table to tblContent (content on the sites) using tblContentSites (siteId,contentId) with composite key siteId+ContentId. I felt repeating an integer ID would be better than the homepage every time in that junction table. Also appreciate thoughts on this.
3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - this seems to me to duplicate the rows but just give the new one a different ID, which is tantamount to duplicating data anyway and could cause my problems down the line. Am I misunderstanding the use of this? Do I have more flexibility of what to do after DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Many thanks,

Drew

Comment: Where do you get a syntax error and which one? Please paste the Error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblSites where homepage='www.a.com')' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Add a unique constraint on the `homepage` column (if you have not already done so):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `tblSites` ADD UNIQUE(`homepage`)
   ```
2. Use `INSERT IGNORE` to only insert if that wouldn't cause a conflict.

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO `tblSites` (`site`, `homepage`) VALUES ('A','www.a.com');
   ```

Comment: Thanks Jack. Is this you saying that my concerns over using homepage as the Id in tblContentSites are unjustified?

Comment: @user3535031 Jack doesn't alter your primary key, he just adds a new constraint to the table that says "this column is unique too"

Comment: Ah I see, OK, thanks! I'd still be interested to know why the current syntax isn't working if you have any ideas on that, but will crack on using Jack's method.

Comment: @user3535031 If homepage is the natural primary key, then by all means, make it so .. otherwise it would make more sense to add a separate index.

Comment: @user3535031 As to why you're getting an error with your query; it's simply not possible to use `WHERE` in an `INSERT` statement :)

Comment: That does actually make a lot of sense when I think about it! I'll mark this as answered then. One final thing though... if I have two or more fields that define a unique entry, how would I extend `INSERT IGNORE` to not add records that match those criteria, if I still used an auto incrementing primary key?

Comment: Scratch that, that's a stupid question. UNIQUE('col1','col2').
Thanks for all your help.